# Random errors with ethernet interface flooding the system log

Tags: linux-mint

I work with a lot of VPNs (vpnc, openvpn, pptp) via WiFi (not using ethernet). There are times where the system log start showing this error:

```
Aug  9 14:39:50 usermsi kernel: [19521.984363] alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: fatal interrupt 0x4019607, resetting
Aug  9 14:39:50 usermsi kernel: [19521.992562] alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: fatal interrupt 0x4019607, resetting
Aug  9 14:39:50 usermsi kernel: [19522.000782] alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: fatal interrupt 0x4019607, resetting
Aug  9 14:39:50 usermsi kernel: [19522.008945] alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: fatal interrupt 0x4019607, resetting
Aug  9 14:39:50 usermsi kernel: [19522.017130] alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: fatal interrupt 0x4019607, resetting

etc etc etc
```

Non stop... filling the disk very fast.

*enp3s0* is the ethernet interface, that i'm not using.

I've tried doing a:

```
#ifconfig enp3s0 down
```

but after some seconds the computer freeze completly.

This is my system info:

```
Linux Mint

#4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

.

```
$ sudo lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet'
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
05:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest if you don't need the Ethernet port, you just remove the driver module (this is a temporary change to the running kernel—it will not persist over a reboot):

```
$ sudo rmmod alx
```

if that leaves your machine running, you can blacklist it so it won't load at all on boot:

```
$ echo 'blacklist alx' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/local-blacklist-alx.conf
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

I would recommend rebooting at that point to confirm it worked (and that it didn't introduce any problems—best to do this when its fresh in your mind, not weeks later):

```
$ lsmod | grep alx
```

should have no output.

As with any kernel or initramfs change, there is a small chance (should be very small) that it won't boot; you should have a recovery disc or some way of fixing that on hand. Especially if this machine is your firewall so you won't have Internet access.

Comment: Thanks.. disabling that at least is still working :) will update in a few days if its all ok (at least one time a day this problem is happening so..)